# QGIS plugin using plugin builder

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I want to create a very simple Python QGIS plugin and I follow this [manual](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html), all works fine using QGIS plugin builder and QT designer but I am not sure how to connect my variable from the GUI to my Python script.

My GUI is simple have only one lineEdit and OK or cancel.

In the GUI (widget):

```
 <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>90</y>
     <width>171</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
```

In the Python script:

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        distance = self.dlg.lineEdit.value()
        if distance == 0:
            #do something
        else:
            #do something else

        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass
```

I test this code but it doesn't work, and doesn't show me anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: In the manual (http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) you have perfectly explained (step by step) how to connect your variable from gui to python script. You should read more carefully.

Comment: i follow step by step but my plugin have different inputs from this i need only a number from line dit

Comment: Your issue is because **QLineEdit** doesn't have any 'value' method. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because **QLineEdit** doesn't have any 'value' method. The correct method is 'text'. Afterward, you need to cast to float (because you require a number for distances). At the Python Console of QGIS I tried out next code:

```
>>>from PyQt4.QtGui import QLineEdit
>>>le = QLineEdit()
>>>le.show()
```

and I wrote **45** at **QLineEdit** object (see next image).

[image]

Again at the Python Console:

```
>>>distance = float(le.text())
>>>distance + 45
90.0
```

If you don't cast to float you get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

So, your issue probably it will fix with this correction (assuming that 'lineEdit' is the correct name for your object):

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        distance = float(self.dlg.lineEdit.text()) #here is the issue
        if distance == 0:
            #do something
        else:
            #do something else

        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass
```

Comment: yes you are correct now working so many thanks,one question more if i run again my plugin without close QGIS in the lineEdit have previous number how to can clear every end ?

Comment: You can use 'clear' method of **QLineEdit** connected to a **QPushButton** named precisely Clear.

Comment: clear method for QLineEdit?